# Java callable threading: keep configuration

Tags: java, multithreading, callable

I am setting up a simulator (for testing) of a server (Radius) which sends queries to another server (LDAP) using threads.
The queries need to be executed on a x per second basis.
I am using a scheduled thread pool executor with callable for this purpose so that I can create callables and submit them to the thread pool for execution.
Each thread should open its own connection and use it to query.
The thing is that I want the connection to be re-used by the same thread every time it is used.

To clarify:

If I have lets say a thread pool of 20 I want 20 connections to be created and used. (so I can send lets say 10.000 queries which will be processed in turn by the 20 threads/connections).

Now the (LDAP) server information to connect to is sent to the constructor of the callable and the callable sets up the connection for execution. Thereafter I retrieve the result using the future system of callable.
The problem with this is each time I create a callable the connection is being opened (and later closed of course).

I am looking for the best practice to keep the connections alive and them being re-used for each thread.

I have thought of some ways to implement this but they dont seem very efficient:

- Use a connection pool inside my threadpool to retrieve a free connection when needed (Creates deadlock and other thread safety issues)
- Use a static (or so) array with connections and [using the thread number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294293/java-how-to-get-thread-id-from-a-thread-pool) to retrieve its connection (Not foul proof either, see link)

*What is the most efficient way of implementing this?* <- old question, see edit for new question.

**EDIT:**
I was thinking because I cannot safely get a thread number, but the threadId is always unique, I can just use a

```
map<String/threadId, connection>
```

And pass the whole map (reference) to the callable. This way I can use something like: (pseudo code)

```
Connection con = map.get(this.getThreadId());
If (con == null){
  con = new Connection(...);
  map.put(this.getThreadId(), con)
}
```

It would also be possible to make the map static and just access it statically. This way I don't have to pass the map to the Callable.
This would be at least safe and doesnt force me to restructure my code.

**New question:**
*What would be closer aligned with best practices; The above solution or Zim-Zam's solution*?
And if the above is best, would it be better to *go for the static solution or not*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement this using a `BlockingQueue` that is shared between `Callables`, with the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` putting `x` queries into the `BlockingQueue` every second

```
public class Worker implements Runnable {
    private final BlockingQueue<Query> inbox;
    private final BlockingQueue<Result> outbox;

    public Worker(BlockingQueue<Query> inbox, BlockingQueue<Result> outbox) {
        // create LDAP connection
        this.inbox = inbox;
        this.outbox = outbox;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while(true) {
                // waits for a Query to be available
                Query query = inbox.take();
                // execute query
                outbox.add(new Result(/* result */));
            }
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
          // log and restart? close LDAP connection and return?
        }
    }
}

public class Master {
   private final int x; // number of queries per second
   private final BlockingQueue<Query> outbox = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(4 * x);
   private final BlockingQueue<Result> inbox = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(4 * x);
   private final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor;
   private final List<Future<?>> workers = new ArrayList<>(20);
   private final Future<?> receiver;

   public Master() {
     // initialize executor
     for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
         Worker worker = new Worker(inbox, outbox);
         workers.add(executor.submit(worker));
     }

     receiver = executor.submit(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
           while(!Thread.interrupted()) {
             try {
               Result result = inbox.take();
               // process result
             } catch(InterruptedException e) {
               return;
             }
           }
         }
     }
   }

   executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           // add x queries to the queue
       }
   }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Use `BlockingQueue#add` to add new `Queries` to `outbox`, if this throws an exception then your queue is full and you'll need to reduce the rate of query creation and/or create more workers.  To break out of a worker's infinite loop call `cancel(true)` on its `Future`, this will throw an `InterruptedException` inside of the `Worker`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Zim-Zam!
It looks good but I need to add two things:
- I use callable so the result of the search gets returned.
- Because I use callable I need the callable(/runnable/worker) to finish execution so the result can be returned. In your example it will keep on running

Comment: @JBre I've edited my answer, there are now two queues: `Master` sends `Query` objects through a `BlockingQueue<Query>` and receives `Result` objects through a `BlockingQueue<Result>`, likewise `Worker` receives `Query` objects and sends `Result` objects

Comment: Thank you for the fast update Zim-Zam!
It looks great and is perfectly usable! I am certainly going to remember this one for future use!
One extra comment though which is about something I have not mentioned yet; Because this is a test application which needs to execute just one test (executing the LDAP queries) I just collect the results later when all queries have been executed. It would be a bit overkill to run an extra thread which processes the results. (And maybe even slightly influence the test results since its taking up resources which will delay the other threads)

Comment: [continuing:] So the question is now what would be best practice in this case?

Thank you again for your perfectly acceptable answer and I am sorry I cannot give you credits yet by approving your answer but I am wondering what would be the best practice.

I edited my answer with a proposition. Could you please take a look and let me know what you think? Your opinion is highly valued :)

Comment: @JBre I would favor your original approach if it didn't cost much to construct a `Worker`/`Callable`, for example if you were accessing a database using a pooled connection or something along those lines.  The input/output queue is more appropriate if, as in this case, it was expensive to create a `Worker`/`Callable` such that it would be appropriate to reuse them.

Comment: Ok thank you for the explanation @Zim-Zam! I will implement my solution but I will still accept your answer since it is a complete answer with a good example. Thank you for your effort!