# Tomcat 7 Maxthreads issues

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, tomcat7

I have set the maxThreads as 32, But in my logs I am seeing way more than the actual count.

```
<Connector port="8080"
                   protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                   maxThreads="32" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443"
                   compression="on"
                   compressionMinSize="512"
                   compressableMimeType="application/json"
        />
```

Logs:

> 24 Oct 2018 13:27:15,378 [INFO,XXX,http-apr-8080-exec-***172***]

Does it mean that this is the 172 thread? I thought the thread pool will be limited to 32 since I have given maxThreads. And I dont have any custom executor defined as well

Comment: That's the thread ID but it doesn't follow that all the 172 IDs are being used for active threads. I recommend you to run some profiling so you can know for sure how many threads are active in the pool.

Comment: What I expect is the pool should ideally have 25 threads and each getting reused. In that case id wont cross 25

Comment: Are you sure that's how the thread pool works?

Comment: im not sure, hence I asked.

Comment: Then, you should not affirm that the ID "won't cross" 25. Please, check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18337222/236345) answer, the ID for threads in Java are not guaranteed to start from zero or to be contiguous when created.

[Here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Thread.java#l217) in the code you can see that their ID is set with a sequence incremented somehow.

Once again, I recommend you to run some profiling tool in your Java app to see the actual number of threads being created in the pool at a given time.

Comment: The pool will shrink down to minSpareThreads="10" (the default value) if threads are not used. If you want more control, configure a separate Executor element.